# Insert text if column contains a number

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, replace

I have a tab-delim file that looks like this

```
10      7.98862e-05
10      cellular organisms; Bacteria; Proteobacteria; Betaproteobacteria; Burkholderiales; Burkholderiaceae; Ralstonia; Ralstonia solanacearum  0.000159772
10      0.000207704
10      cellular organisms; Bacteria; Terrabacteria group; Firmicutes; Clostridia; Clostridiales; Clostridiaceae; Clostridium; Clostridium sp. C105KSO15        0.00092668
10      9.58635e-05
10      0.000191727
10      0.000127818
10      cellular organisms; Bacteria; Terrabacteria group; Firmicutes; Clostridia; Clostridiales; Peptostreptococcaceae; Clostridioides; Clostridioides difficile       0.0                                                               0142198
10      cellular organisms; Bacteria; Terrabacteria group; Firmicutes; Clostridia; Clostridiales; Clostridiaceae; Clostridium; Clostridium sp. C105KSO15        0.00268418
```

It should be three columns but some rows are missing the second column (bacterial taxonomy). For these rows I want to move the number to a third column and insert some text (such as `Unclassified`).

I have been attempting to modify some commands I found online to insert `Unclassified\t` before any value in the second column which starts with a number but have been unable to get it working.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

give this line a try:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" 'NF==2{$3=$2;$2="Unclassified"}7' file
```

Comment: I think I follow all of it but what does the ``7`` do?

Comment: @cazzlewazzle89 the non-zero number does default action: `print`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this sed too

```
sed -E 's/([^\t]*\t)([0-9]\.[0-9].*$)/\1Unclassified\t\2/' infile
```